# Image doesn't display although there's data in MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql

Currently, I have a problem with my project. In the MySQL database, there are two columns named `photo before` and `photo_after` with formated **BLOB**. I use `base64` to decode the image when displaying it to a PHP page.

The main problem is if there have data in column `photo_before` or `photo_after` it still displays '**noimage.jpg**'. I don't know why. Below is my code:

```
<?php
$report_id = $_GET['report_id'];


$sql = "SELECT * FROM report LEFT JOIN users ON report.badgeid = users.badgeid LEFT JOIN team ON team.team_id = users.team_id WHERE report_id = :report_id";
$query = $conn->prepare($sql);
$query->execute(array(':report_id' => $report_id));
while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

    $report_id = $row["report_id"];
    $report_date = $row["report_date"];
    $task_name = $row["task_name"];
    $photo_before = $row["photo_before"];
    $photo_after = $row["photo_after"];
    $ot_start = $row["ot_start"];
    $ot_end = $row["ot_end"];
    $time_photo_before = $row["time_photo_before"];
    $time_photo_after = $row["time_photo_after"];
    $report_status = $row["report_status"];

}

?>

<tr>
  <td rowspan = '2'><b>Before Task</b></td>

  <?php
    if(!isset($row['photo_before']) || empty($row['photo_before'])) {
        echo "<td colspan='3'><img src='../../images/faces/noimage.png'/></td>";
      }else{ 
              echo "<td colspan='3'><img src='data:image/jpeg;base64,".$row['photo_before']."'/></td>"; 
      }
  ?>

</tr>
<tr>
  <td colspan='3'><?php echo "Time: <b>" .$time_photo_before."</b>"; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td rowspan = '2'><b>After Task</b></td>
  <?php
    if(!isset($row['photo_after']) || empty($row['photo_after'])) {
        echo "<td colspan='3'><img src='../../images/faces/noimage.png'/></td>";
      }else{ 
              echo "<td colspan='3'><img src='data:image/jpeg;base64,".$row['photo_after']."'/></td>"; 
      }
  ?>
</tr>
```

Comment: `while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))` will fetch the next result set and assign it to `$row` until it return false and stop the loop. You are calling $row after the loop when its value is `false`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The empty() function returns true or false 
It returns FALSE when variable data exists and has a non-empty, non-zero value. Otherwise it returns TRUE.
add and try, hope it will work:

```
if(!isset($row['photo_after']) || empty($row['photo_after'])== 'true/false')
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the problem is on Your `if( the problem is here )`, the || / or logical sends true if 0|1,1|0 and 1|1...check Your php version too where `".$row['photo_before']."` your " is using the " or ', mine using `'.$row['photo_before'].'`